# Why does this code print 2? What does it do?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, lambda, printing

Why does this code print 2?
I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the order of the calls and what happens when the code runs. I'd like to know what's going on here, thanks!

The code:

```
mia = lambda dan: lambda john: list(john)[dan]
john = lambda mia: lambda dan: filter(dan, map(lambda x: x % 2 + 1, mia))

ta = mia(-1)(john([3, 6, 9, 12, 15])(lambda f: f % 3))
print(ta)
```

Comment: Rewrite the code with normal functions instead of lambdas. Then add some print statements to see what's going on during execution. Then ask here about a specific part of the code you don't understand. We don't do "please explain everything" questions.

Comment: Nit: they are normal functions. Rewrite the lambda expressions with `def` statements. (Both produce `function` objects.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some kind of obfuscated way to perform a simple task:

1. check if numbers in a list are odd or even and map 1, 2 accordingly
2. filter the previous output if this is not a multiple of 3 (which is always True)
3. take the last item of the previous output

In summary, this output 2 if the last number of the input is odd and 1 otherwise.

This could be simplified to:

```
list(map(lambda x: x % 2 + 1, [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]))[-1]
```

or, keeping the useless filter:

```
list(filter(lambda f: f % 3, map(lambda x: x % 2 + 1, [3, 6, 9, 12, 15])))[-1]
```

This is using a functional approach in which the functions return functions instead of values. In addition the local variables have names designed to be confusing (`mia` in `john` has nothing to do with the `mia` function)

Interestingly, `mia` is equivalent to [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

Comment: @timgeb I just did it for fun ;) I got motivated once I realized `mia` is actually a simple implementation of `operator.itemgetter`

Answer (score 1):

It does a lot less than it looks like.

To simplify, turn the lambda expressions into `def` statements.

```
def mia(dan):
    def inner(john):
        lst = list(john)
        return lst[dan]
    return inner

def john(mia):
    def inner(dan):
        mp = map(lambda x: x % 2 + 1, mia)
        return filter(dan, mp)
    return inner
```

To simplify further, separate your function calls.

```
# just return the inner function
john_inner_func = john([3, 6, 9, 12, 15])
# first map element % 2 + 1 to each element of the given array
# this results in [2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
# next it filters all truthy (non-zero) values of the result of element % 3. 
# Since all are positive and less than 3 the result is the same
# [2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
john_filter_result = john_inner_func(lambda f: f % 3)
# just return the inner function
mia_inner_func = mia(-1)
# return the -1 index of the filter result as a list
# this gives the last element, or 2
ta = mia_inner_func(john_filter_result)
print(ta)
```